# Jupyter notebook signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

whenever I run python in jupyter, it gives me this: 
ValueError: signal only works in main thread

[image]

Comment: This should help you: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4934

Comment: Hi tried I get this :(base) C:\Users\Kevin Boss>pip install "tornado>=5.0"
Collecting tornado>=5.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/d6/4e4a9282a3fb8555dca2369e827bd844c7f2d1a59c5790d3bfd97eb66206/tornado-5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: tornado
  Found existing installation: tornado 4.5.1
Cannot uninstall 'tornado'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 34):

Worked for me - Windows 10. Jupyter Lab

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04  as well

Comment: Getting an error saying that I can't uninstall ipykernel. What shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

Only worked when downgraded to tornado 5.1.1,

Then :
pip install pip --upgrade,

pip install --upgrade notebook,

I have python 3.6.8 and MAC

Answer (score 0):

I use anaconda with python 3.7. updating tornado package for jupyter worked for me :

```
conda install tornado --update
```

Answer found in this post :
[Jupyter Notebook dead Kernel after Anaconda update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603097/jupyter-notebook-dead-kernel-after-anaconda-update)