# Jupyter notebook does not run any command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am not able to run any command in jupyter notebook.

```
handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback (<zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object at 0x04378E70>, <function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x0437CD68>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "c:\python27\lib\signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
[I 10:57:51.456 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: fbbad76c-f291-476b-9307-f3789746cf4c
```

Please consider below points.

1. When I run any command say simple print('hello'), cell keeps running for   infinite time.
2. I installed dark theme using

   `pip install jupyterthemes 
   jt -t onedork`
3. There was error on the above and I upgraded pip from 18.0 to 18.1 and then jupyter notebook from 4.3 to 4.4.
4. It was working fine until yesterday.
5. From Morning I am facing this problem and I tried to uninstall and reinstall jupyter notebook which did not work and then downgrade pip from 18.1 to 18.0, uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter notebook. But it did not work.
6. I changed the jupyter theme back to original using `jt -r` but no solution.
7. Also I added dark theme (dark reader) for my firefox yesterday and disabled it. But same situation.
8. I again reinstalled notebook 4.3 version with a warning

   `Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from html5lib>=0.99999999->bleach->nbconvert->notebook==4.3) (0.5.1)
   widgetsnbextension 2.0.0 has requirement notebook>=4.4.1, but you'll have notebook 4.3.0 which is incompatible.
   jupyterthemes 0.19.6 has requirement notebook>=5.6.0, but you'll have notebook 4.3.0 which is incompatible.
   Installing collected packages: notebook
     Found existing installation: notebook 5.7.0
       Uninstalling notebook-5.7.0:
         Successfully uninstalled notebook-5.7.0
   Successfully installed notebook-4.3.0
   You are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

But nothing worked.

9. I am using 
   windows 10. 
   Python 3.6
   pip 18.0
   jupyter notebook 4.3.0

Please help and let me know if other information is required. I tried to search for similar problem but could not get solution.

Comment: Why do you need to install themes, give a simple shot to `python3 -m pip install jupyter` or `pip3 install jupyter`.
Also, please ensure that `ipython` is installed. I'm not sure whether jupyter installs it internally. Refer: http://jupyter.org/install

Comment: I started facing this problem after installing dark theme. which I removed later on. Not sure what is the problem. python, jupyter notebook everything was working fine. I have another instance of jupyter notebook which I got through anaconda. Also everything seems to work on the other one. I have tried running the commands through IDLE of python. Everything is working fine. But the one which I have mentioned above is the primary one which I am working most of the time and it is higher version as well. So I am asking for some help to help me bring it back up ad running.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. At the first place, I checked command prompt logs. The error was:

> ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback

And the solution that worked for me:

> Uninstalling goole-colab and upgrading ipykernel, by commands:
>
> pip uninstall google-colab
>
> pip install --upgrade ipykernel

Reference: [Jupyter Notebook dead Kernel after Anaconda update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603097/jupyter-notebook-dead-kernel-after-anaconda-update)