# Why won't basic code execute in Jupiter (import pandas as pd)?

Tags: python, jupyter

I just downloaded Anaconda on a new laptop (have used Python many times before), and I currently can't run any code in Jupiter Notebooks. I am stuck in [*] no matter how simple the code (i.e. import pandas as pd or say x=1). Any suggestions on how to fix this? So far I have tried restarting Anaconda and shutting down the code in the running tab.

Comment: Can you post the logs from the terminal window where you ran `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: Here are a few lmk if this helps : 
[I 12:25:52.907 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
[W 12:31:18.627 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/aac1dc7b-3480-40b6-b28b-2a915ead1238/channels?session_id=f3efca9c037440208b1c57bf925bf6bd (::1): Kernel does not exist: aac1dc7b-3480-40b6-b28b-2a915ead1238
[W 12:31:18.633 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/aac1dc7b-3480-40b6-b28b-2a915ead1238/channels?session_id=f3efca9c037440208b1c57bf925bf6bd (::1) 12.120000ms referer=None
[W 12:31:21.866 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: aac1dc7b-3480-40b6-b28b-2a915ead1238:f3efca9c037440208b1c57bf9

Comment: [W 19:31:31.052 NotebookApp] Notebook Algo Trading 1.ipynb is not trusted
[I 19:31:31.211 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 92a8189a-be7a-43f4-b291-abd4e243220e, name: python3
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
This might be the cause. @thomaskeefe

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs, take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603097/jupyter-notebook-dead-kernel-after-anaconda-update). Otherwise, googling `python3 ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream` may help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  The solution is not anywhere on stack overflow or Google.  The answer to this problem is only on YouTube, which I found slightly surprising.  Essentially, I had two versions of Anaconda, because it would seem that Macs come with an older version of Anaconda already installed in a hidden file called opt.  I had to locate this file and then delete it in the terminal. Once Anaconda was completely removed, I was able to re-download Anaconda and then Jupyter was able to launch smoothly.

For anyone else having this problem you can find the solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJ_JTgq8-m8